# How to share a GNU sed script between Linux and Mac OS X

Tags: scripting, sed, portability, shebang

I have a GNU `sed` script I use on Linux; it is installed at `/bin/sed` and it seems it contains GNUisms. I have collaborators using Mac OS X. They have installed (non-GNU) `sed`, located at `/usr/bin/sed`, and using Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) can install GNU `sed` as `gsed` with the *coreutils* package, located at `/usr/local/bin/gsed`.

Currently, the script starts with `#!/bin/sed -f`. How do I modify it so that it can be run on Mac OS X, when GNU `sed` is installed as `gsed`?

Another option would be to remove the GNUisms, but this may be a bit hard, as I do not have a Mac OS X install at hand and cannot ask my collaborators to test intermediate versions.

Comment: I have no OS X to test this on, but wouldn't `#!/usr/bin/env sed` work on both OS X and Linux? That would make things much more portable and it is the reason why env always should be used rather than fixed paths).

Comment: @Hennes: well, the problem is that on OS X, the `sed` I want would be called `gsed`, but your suggestion would work if the script does not contain any GNUisms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options:

- Use `#!/usr/bin/gsed -f` (assuming it is in `/usr/bin`) as the shebang everywhere, and make sure that your Linux environments symlink this properly;
- Remove the GNUisms;
- Symlink `sed` to `/usr/bin/gsed` from a directory that earlier than `/usr/bin` in the user's `$PATH` (possibly dangerous);
- Make a wrapper script that looks something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

script=/foo

type gsed >/dev/null 2>&1 && exec gsed -f "$script"
exec sed -f "$script"
```

Ultimately there either need to be changes to at least one of the environments, or changes to the script itself.

Answer (score 5):

You could have your `sed` script start with this instead:

```
\:;s=sed;type gsed >/dev/null 2>&1 && s=gsed; exec "$s" -f "$0" "$@";$:s/^//
```

That's a no-op in `sed` (though would slightly degrade your script performance) and when interpreted by a shell would execute with `gsed` if found or `sed` if not (both looked up in `$PATH`).

Comment: Ah, would

    `\:;s=sed;command -v gsed >/dev/null && s=gsed; exec "$s" -f "$0" "$@";$:s/^//`

then be more portable?

Comment: Would ``\:;`command -v gsed || command -v sed` -f "$0" "$@";$:s/^//`` be a portable alternative?

Comment: I don't think `command -v` is significantly more portable than `type`. Both are optional in POSIX, required by Unix. Some old non-POSIX shells like variants of the Bourne shell, have `type` but not `command -v` (though some older ones don't set the exit status to non-zero on command-not-found). `posh` has neither. I once reported to the LSB that having neither was a problem, they acknowledged it, I though they did something about it, but now quickly looking at the latest spec, there doesn't seem to be any `type` or `command` command (!?).

Comment: Correction. [LSB now does mandate](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/command.html#AEN32061) both `type` and `command` (though I don't see that it says whether `-v` should be supported). So it looks like `type` is required by the LSB, but (maybe) not `command -v`.

Answer (score 1):

(Giving an answer to my own question, or rather, an alternative approach that will work in this situation.)

A `sed` script `ascript.sed`, even when they start with a sha-bang, can also be applied from the command line on a target file `target.txt` as `sed -f ascript.sed target.txt`. This means that when on Mac OS X, one can call the script as `gsed -f ascript.sed target.txt`.